# WinRT 8.1: How to hide Flyout after calling a method on the viewModel

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, caliburn.micro

I have a Flyout in my Win 8.1 application that is calling a method on the viewModel using the convention.  That works fine.  How can I hide/close the Flyout once the method have been called?  Using code-behind, it would be `f.hide()` but I can't figure it out with Caliburn.Micro.

Here's my XAML and ViewModel method.

```
<Button Content="Add Income / Expense"  Margin="35,0,0,0">
                <Button.Flyout>
                    <Flyout>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBox Name="LabelToAdd" Header="Enter Label name of income / expense:"/>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Button Name="btn_Add" Content="Add"></Button>
                                <Button Name="btn_Cancel" Content="Cancel"></Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Flyout>
                </Button.Flyout>
            </Button>
```

Method:

```
    public void btn_Add()
    {

        _income.Add(new Transaction (_labelToAdd,  10.00M, DateTime.Now));
        _labelToAdd = string.Empty;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => LabelToAdd);
    // Hiding the Flyout here?
    }
```

Thanks very much for any input, 
Martin.

Answer (score 1):

what i did and it seems to be working was created an property of type action on my flyout view model

```
   public Action CloseFlyout { get; set; }
```

and in my calling view model i set it to the hide method

```
  var regionflyout = new RegionFlyout();
  var vm = regionflyout.DataContext as RegionViewModel;
  vm.CloseFlyout = ()=> regionflyout.Hide();

  regionflyout.ShowIndependent();
```

and then finally in my Flyout viewmodel i invoke the CloseFlyout action.

```
  this.CloseFlyout.Invoke();
```

not sure how great of an approach this is, but it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind flyout visibilite to a property. And then just set it to false in the method:

```
private bool showFlyout;

public bool ShowFlyout
{
    get
    { 
        return showFlyout;
    }
    set
    {
        showFlyout = value; 
        PropertyChanged("ShowFlyout");
    }
}

public void btn_Add()
{
    _income.Add(new Transaction (_labelToAdd,  10.00M, DateTime.Now));
    _labelToAdd = string.Empty;
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => LabelToAdd);
    ShowFlyout = false;
}
```

It is assumed that your class implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Also btn_Add() is not a good identifier for a method in C#. It's better to use PascalCase.

Comment: Thanks for helping out.  It seems the Flyout does not have a  Visibility.  So I bind it to the StackPanel Visibility and the StackPanel does disappear.  But there is still a white box, an empty Flyout, that stays there.   Any idea? 

Thanks for the method naming convention, I modified my method name.

Comment: Found the following link:
https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/07/30/using-windows-8-1-flyout-xaml-control-with-mvvm/

It is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for taking the time appreciated.